# Owl Carousel / Flex Carousel

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel, owl-carousel

I'm trying to make a flex carousel that has the properties of flexboxes in CSS. Features like as flex-shrink. I tried to contain a the bootstrap  carousel in a flex container but it doesn't have the flex. I am using the owl carousel now but it doesn't do a single item slideshow.

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  center:true,
  items: 1,
  nav:true,
  rewind:true,
  dots:true,
  autoHeight:true,
  autoWidth:true,

})
 <div id="owl" class="owl-carousel">

<div class="item"><img src="pic1.jpg" alt="picture1missing"></div>
<div class="item"><img src="pic2.jpg" alt="picture2missing"></div>
<div class="item"><img src="pic3.jpg" alt="picture3missing"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

> Refer My Codepen -- [Click here](https://codepen.io/AK96/pen/dgzMgB) for your answer

```
multi item carousel
```